# Select by attributes ModelBuilder - text string partial values for parameter

Tags: modelbuilder, select-by-attribute, arcgis-10.5, text, querystring

I have a feature class of suburbs that I want to do a select by attribute on the Locality (=suburb names) field, passing a user input string parameter to selection expression.

I have the query working when the string parameter is the full Locality name - the working query is ***UPPER("LOCALITY") = UPPER('%String%')***. The Locality string values are title case.

I want the user to be able to pass a string that is only part of the full locality string, as the parameter for the expression. In the data I have localities Mount Jeff, Jeffs Point, Jefferson - I want the user to be able to input "Jeff" as the parameter text string and select these three occurences.

I think my confusion is with how to add the wildcard to the ***UPPER('%String%')*** to indicate that the parameter string may only be part of the text field value. My previous use of  wildcards has been using the % character but cannot get my head around this expression where the % character is also used to identify the parameter.

Currently at home working off a shapefile copy of the data, (finished model will be pointing to an SDE/enterprise feature class).

Comment: Have a look at the help file, it's all there, you are wanting to build an expression using the [LIKE operator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/map/working-with-layers/building-a-query-expression.htm).

Comment: An equivalence operator is the wrong logical test -- instead use `LIKE`. Shapefile and enterprise databases have very different SQL comparison tools, so the former is not a good prototype environment for the latter.